# What is the difference between the "Java Project" and "Project" options in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm an absolute Java beginner and I wanted to create my first HelloWorld application using Eclipse. But when I went on and clicked "New" I could see the two options I mentioned in my question - Java Project and Java. What actually is their difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option `"New Java Project"` is a shortcut for the steps `"New Project" -> "Java" -> "Java Project"`. The project templates differ the folder structure and files that will be generated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you know you can use eclipse with many other compilers as well. If you have anyother compiler installed and cofigured with eclipse then you can click on project and then create project of that kind.

One more thing: If you want to do some embedded programming then you better chose project instead of java project because it will not let you place the module of other type in same package, you can use it outside of package as folder but not inside.

Simple: Project is for more about embedded prgramming and java-project is for only with java-classes in package, you can place modules in source-folders but that's dirty work.

I use sometime haskell, mostly prolog with Java for some A.I problems. You can see you get different option.
[image]